# powershell: activate python virtualenv using shortcut

Tags: python, windows, powershell

All my virtualenvs are put into a `venv` folder which is inside the project folder.

If I want to activate the virtualenv when inside the project folder I need to enter:

```
.\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

Having to do this many times I really find this cumbersome. And I am looking for something quicker. From inside my project folder I'd like to type `act` or something which then automatically activates the `.ps1` script.

But not being familiar with powershell and all the options available I wonder if someone could give me some clues where to start ? (batch script? cmd script? powershell script? shortcut (`.lnk`) file?)

Thanks !

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. Thus, I have rolled back your edit. You can still get the text from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66704570/revisions); if you think it adds value here, please do feel welcome to post the solution as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is called an alias

In Windows you will use it this way :

```
New-Alias <nom-alias> <commande>
```

To make it persistant (be able to use it again after closing and reopening the powershell) you need to put the alias in a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

WORKED_OUT_SOLUTION. credits to answer from Tim.

In your powershell:

```sh
# create an alias called "ve" that looks for the relative location of -Value
# and runs it.
New-Alias -Name ve -Value venv/scripts/activate.ps1

# Export the alias to a script.
Export-Alias -Name ve -Path "venv.ps1" -As Script

# Make sure this scripts runs each time you start a powershell session.
Add-Content -Path $Profile -Value (Get-Content venv.ps1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function finds the activation script in your project and runs it.

```
Function venv_activate {
    Get-ChildItem activate.ps1 -Recurse -Depth 2 | %{$_.FullName} | Invoke-Expression
}
```

[image]